# exporting symbols in a dynamic qt library

Tags: c++, qt4, qmake, dylib

I'm trying to create a dynamic library using Qt on OS X 10.6.7 and Qt 4.7.3. I have created the most basic test I can think of (see below or https://gist.github.com/1016045) and yet

```
otool -T build/libstackoverflow.dylib
```

still reports

```
build/libstackoverflow.dylib:
Table of contents (0 entries)
module index symbol index
```

I'm assuming I should see something else in that list related to factorial.

Test case (also at: https://gist.github.com/1016045):

```
// main.cpp

#include <stdint.h>
#include <QtCore/QtGlobal>

#if defined(MYSHAREDLIB_LIBRARY)
#  define MYSHAREDLIB_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#  define MYSHAREDLIB_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif

MYSHAREDLIB_EXPORT uint64_t factorial(int max) {
    int i           = max;
    uint64_t result = 1;

    while (i >= 2)
        result *= i--;

    return result;
}


// stackoverflow.pro

TEMPLATE = lib
DEFINES += MYSHAREDLIB_LIBRARY
CONFIG += qt dll
TARGET = 
DEPENDPATH += .
INCLUDEPATH += .
DESTDIR = ./build

# Input
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

To build:

```
qmake
make
```

I've read:

- [Creating Custom QT Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763259/creating-custom-qt-library)
- http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.7/sharedlibrary.html

Please recommend other resources if applicable!

EDIT:

I believe the symbols might be being exported correctly, although their names are mangled (or at least appear to be), which I thought using the Q_DECL_EXPORT macro was supposed to avoid. For example, here is the result of running nm -g build/libstackoverflow.dylib:

```
0000000000001f20 T __Z9factoriali
                 U ___gxx_personality_v0
                 U dyld_stub_binder
```

Is this what I should expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think just exporting will disable C++ name mangling. If you have "plain C" functions you want to export without mangling, you'll need to wrap their declaration in an `extern "C" {}` block (in a header preferably of course).

Name mangling doesn't prevent successful linking, as long as the "client" code is also compiled with a C++ compiler. If you want them both available to C and C++, the `extern "C"`, conditionally defined depending on C/C++ compiler, is necessary AFAIK.

Comment: In this case, I'm compiling a Qt library and attempting to reference it using node-ffi (https://github.com/rbranson/node-ffi/). Adding the extern "C" did make the symbols available! So thanks for the suggestion!